# Не устанавливается денвер и xampp

Tags: apache, denwer

После того, как я удалил Денвер и попытался установить (попытка, кстати, оказалась провальной) я решил вернутся на денвер. Но при установки выскакивает сообщение

> AllowToModifyVirtualHosts:
> Makes the file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` writable by everyone
> Success: the hosts file is marked as writable.
> (c) Dmitry Koterov(dmitry@koterov.ru) - хотя я такого мыла не вписывал
> (c)Denwer project: http://denwer.ru

Также пробывал установить xampp, там не включается apache

При установке также выскакивает сообщение с указанием на папку programm files.

Comment: Я как-то споткнулся, пока читал первое предложение. Вас ничего не смущает?

Answer (score 1):

Ну а что тебя напугало? Перевести-то пробовал сообщения? Ну а адрес, который ты не вписывал - это адрес разработчика (если не ошибаюсь) денвера, ну или кого-то из команды разрабов. Ничего пока страшного не вижу, посмотри права на hosts, возможно юзера ВСЕ придётся выкинуть из ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Запусти от имени администратора